# Django: Get the ManyToMany object of ManyToManyField

Tags: django, database, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I know I can fetch all authors of a paper like:

```
paper.authors.all()
```

This works fine, but just returns me a QuerySet of Authors.

But I want the ManyToMany Object like (because I want to sort after the ID's)

> (id *(BigAutoField)*, paper, author)

Is there a faster way to do it then:

```
Paper.authors.through.objects.all().filter(paper=paper)
```

Because my Database is really Large ~200 million entries, the command above is not feasible

My Model looks like:

```
class Paper(models.Model, ILiterature):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)
    (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select in bulk,

```py
papers = Paper.authors.through.in_bulk(ids)
```

Django bulk commands are faster and designed for massive DB's like yours. You can check https://levelup.gitconnected.com/optimizing-django-queries-28e96ad204de here for details.

Comment: This doenst solve the problem :( still too slow.